# Grabbing network information from a webpage using Playwright

Tags: node.js, playwright

I am trying to grab the GraphQL payloads that are captured in the network tab when my webpage loads, is there a standard way to do this? I'm quite inexperienced with Playwright so sure its easy enough but all of my Googling has led me here.

I have tried using Google!

Answer (score 2):

[Monitoring Network](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#network-events)

With playwright, you can monitor all the [Requests](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-request) and [Responses](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-response) on a page:

```
// Subscribe to 'request' and 'response' events.
page.on('request', request => console.log('>>', request.method(), request.url()));
page.on('response', response => console.log('<<', response.status(), response.url()));

await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

Or wait for a network response after the button click with [page.waitForResponse()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response):

```
// Use a glob URL pattern. Note no await.
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse('**/api/fetch_data');
await page.getByText('Update').click();
const response = await responsePromise;
```