Playwright - Get Last Failed API Request
We have bigger number of playwright tests running on daily basis. Sometimes, test fails due to some API calls which is failing with status code other than 200.  When tests are failing, we would like to have script to get last failed API call and get it's response message. Do we have mechanism available with Playwright library to get that ? There is no specific API call which will fail. Any API call can fail randomly.

This is a bit broad. I don't think there's a built in command for this. Can you share a [mcve] to see how you're doing these requests and what your overall test setup and failing output looks like? There are multiple ways to do this, best is probably reading from the report JSON.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76255884/1831456

A not very elegant solution could be using page.on to monitor all requests:
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";

let lastFailedApiCall;

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  page.on("response", (response) => {
    if (!response.ok()) lastFailedApiCall = response;
  });
});

test("Test", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://httpstat.us/404");
  await page.goto("https://httpstat.us/502");
  await page.goto("https://httpstat.us/500");

  // Fail the test on purpose
  expect(true).toBe(false);
});

test.afterEach(async ({}, testInfo) => {
  if (testInfo.status === "failed") {
    // Log information about the failed API call:
    console.log(
      "Last failed API call:",
      lastFailedApiCall.status(),
      lastFailedApiCall.url(),
      await lastFailedApiCall.text()
    );
  }
  // Returns:
  // Last failed API call: 500 https://httpstat.us/500 500 Internal Server Error
});


